# Как перевести выражение с jQuery на чистый js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#administrator').submit();
```

Не получается переписать это на js. Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById('administrator').submit();
```

Comment: Я думаю правильно будет `querySelector`, потому что в jquery через #

Comment: document.querySelector('#administrator').submit(); Есть разница?

Comment: да, потому что `querySelector` выбирает по селектору, типа `.parent-elem .elem .administrator` почти как в `jquery`. `getElementById` может выбрать только по id

Comment: Я это понимаю. Какая разница в работе кода?

Comment: Это и есть вся разница

Comment: Разницы нет, код выполняет одинаковые задачи. Методы, объекты, аргументы могут отличатся

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107882/discussion-between---and--).

Comment: @МихаилКамахин Селектор работает пока медленнее. Думаю идентификаторы браузер индексирует куда лучше [getelementbyid-vs-queryselector](https://web.archive.org/web/20160108040024/http://jsperf.com/getelementbyid-vs-queryselector)

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg в вопросе не спрашивали как сделать быстрее